# Google map is not showing above specific dimensions

Tags: google-maps

Google map is not showing above 650px in width. Working fine @ <= 650px.
OR
If i increase width, i need to decrease height.
say:

```
width: 780px, height: 450px; 
width: 650px, height: 600px;
```

Can I increase both ?? OR is there any aspect ratio problem ??

Answer (score 0):

No there will not be any aspect ratio problem, you can increase height or width of map div, but if your screen's resolution is not supported then it will display scroll and you will need to scroll down to access zoom in/out button

Comment: nops....it is not even displaying if i increase the area more than that i told.. any ways thanks